# Adding a variable to an existing constraint on pyomo

Tags: pyomo

I have the constraint **z_1 + z_2 = 1** in a concrete model. I want to add another variable z_n at the nth step of solving. E.g. the constraint would become **z_1 + z_2 + z_3 = 1** in the first step of solving and  **z_1 + z_2 + z_3 + z_4 = 1** in the next step, and so on.

I really appreciate it if anyone has a suggestion

Thanks a lot!

I am using ConstraintList() method and one way that came to my mind was deleting the constraint in each step and rewriting that. But I am not sure how to do it and if it is efficient or not.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do what you want.  The simplest is to update the constraint in question with a new relational expression:

```py
>>> import pyomo.environ as pyo
>>> m = pyo.ConcreteModel()
>>> m.z = pyo.Var(range(5))
>>> m.c = pyo.Constraint(expr=m.z[0] + m.z[1] == 1)
>>> m.c.pprint()
c : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
    Key  : Lower : Body        : Upper : Active
    None :   1.0 : z[0] + z[1] :   1.0 :   True
>>> m.c.set_value(m.c.body + m.z[2] == m.c.upper)
>>> m.c.pprint()
c : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
    Key  : Lower : Body               : Upper : Active
    None :   1.0 : z[0] + z[1] + z[2] :   1.0 :   True
>>> m.c.set_value(m.c.body + m.z[3] == m.c.upper)
>>> m.c.pprint()
c : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
    Key  : Lower : Body                      : Upper : Active
    None :   1.0 : z[0] + z[1] + z[2] + z[3] :   1.0 :   True
```

Alternatively, an approach that requires less manipulation of the model is to use an `Expression` (named expression) component to hold the constraint body and just update that expression:

```py
>>> m = pyo.ConcreteModel()
>>> m.z = pyo.Var(range(5))
>>> m.e = pyo.Expression(expr=m.z[0] + m.z[1])
>>> m.c = pyo.Constraint(expr=m.e == 1)
>>> m.c.pprint()
c : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
    Key  : Lower : Body : Upper : Active
    None :   1.0 :    e :   1.0 :   True
>>> m.e.pprint()
e : Size=1, Index=None
    Key  : Expression
    None : z[0] + z[1]
>>> m.e.expr += m.z[2]
>>> m.c.pprint()
c : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
    Key  : Lower : Body : Upper : Active
    None :   1.0 :    e :   1.0 :   True
>>> m.e.pprint()
e : Size=1, Index=None
    Key  : Expression
    None : z[0] + z[1] + z[2]
>>> m.e.expr += m.z[3]
>>> m.c.pprint()
c : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
    Key  : Lower : Body : Upper : Active
    None :   1.0 :    e :   1.0 :   True
>>> m.e.pprint()
e : Size=1, Index=None
    Key  : Expression
    None : z[0] + z[1] + z[2] + z[3]
```

Comment: Thanks for your useful answer. I used the second one and I defined the constraints but I think there is a problem with solving it. "Solver failed to return an optimal solution. Solver status: ok, Termination condition: infeasible" error pops up. Is there a problem with this way of definition?
Also, I couldn't use the first one because Z variables are defined on two sets and I must use rule component instead of expr.

Comment: Both approaches are compatible with rules (rules are called to initially construct components; this answer is dealing with updating components after construction).  As for the solver termination condition, that is indicating that the solver determined that your model as posed was infeasible.  While I have seen rare cases where a solver returned infeasible for a feasible model (usually due to poor scaling and/or errors in the solver's presolve step), the usual cause is that your model (as posed) is infeasible.